# no name alias in keystore file (P12)

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, pkcs#12, truststore

Received a keystore file fac_sign.p12 to get the production access with keystore password but when I view the details of the certificate there no alias name to get the certificate. Below is the result(copied just top lines) when I run the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore usr/local/HIService/Keys/fac_sign.p12
-storetype PKCS12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE
Your keystore contains 1 entry
Alias name:
Creation date: Jan 15, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Specialist :7786786786, OU=Specialist, O=Specialist, L=MT HELEN, ST=VIC, C=AU
Issuer: CN=Medicare Australia Organisation Certification Authority, OU=Medicare Australia, O=GOV, C=AU
Serial number: 4abcd
Valid from: Wed Feb 19 12:40:07 EST 2014 until: Tue Feb 19 12:39:59 EST 2019
Certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  4C:B2:A4:6C:5D:B7:71:7A:35:4A:39:33:D7:87:64:93
SHA1: C7:46:01:A3:B9:A6:E4:D3:7E:5D:98:9D:D3:22:B9:7A:B6:D1:79:66
```

In java code below line of code is returning NULL because keystoreAlias=""

```
(KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore.getEntry(keystoreAlias,new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keystorePassword.toCharArray()));
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because OpenJDK 8/9 has a bug which prevents loading keys with empty aliases. But it's easy to change the alias using `keytool`.

```
keytool -changealias -alias "" -destalias "new-alias" -keystore ./keystore.p12
```

Answer (score 0):

Open with "keystore explorer" (http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html), change alias field and save.